How to access variable properties of `this` while satisfying typescript?
This is what I'm currently doing:
setOps = (ops: Partial<Ops>) => {
    let key: keyof Ops;
    for (key in ops) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // @ts-ignore
        this[key] = ops[key];
      }
    }
  };

I've checked that the approach does work in runtime, but I'd like to get this working without the @ts-ignore. If I remove it as-is, typescript will object on these grounds: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
Is there a way I can define the key type of this somehow, or a way I could approach this differently that typescript will approve of?
Minimum reproducible example:
type Ops = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

class Tester {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  constructor(ops: Ops) {
    this.a = ops.a;
    this.b = ops.b;
  }
  setOps = (ops: Partial<Ops>) => {
    let key: keyof Ops;
    for (key in ops) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // @ts-ignore
        this[key] = ops[key];
      }
    }
  }
}


const tester = new Tester({a: 'a', b: 1});


console.log(tester.a, tester.b);


tester.setOps({a: 'aa'});


console.log(tester.a, tester.b);


tester.setOps({b: 2});


console.log(tester.a, tester.b);


Updated with a copy-able example.

Ah, there are a few things biting you here. One is ms/TS#32693, and the workaround is to switch to generics. Another is that this can be a subtype of Tester since you can subclass it, and the workaround is to widen it explicitly (which leaves open a safety hole but that's what you want to do anyway).  See this playground link. And note that what you really want to do here is Object.assign(this, ops); instead of the loop. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks so much! That did indeed solve it, though I had to go through a few other hoops to get my actual this to be "widen-able" to the Ops type (unsure about the terminology there, or what's actually being done under the hood since I would think this should theoretically be a superset of Ops? but I digress), the changes were things that cleaned up the code anyhow. Should work as an answer ^-^

I wouldn't recommend doing this at all. It's very unsafe and, IMO, TS should have an even stronger error for it. Because right you saw the code didn't compile and figured "I have to muck around with the code so it compiles" rather than "I need a different approach" https://tsplay.dev/WPQ9zw

I believe @jcalz solution avoids the issue you highlight, but correct me if I'm wrong.

No, it doesn't avoid that issue. If you want to avoid that issue you need to filter out any keys that are not in Ops.  I'm mentioning various pitfalls in the answer I'm writing

The simplest solution is also the dumbest - just don't loop. Grab the keys you know you need - like you did in the constructor with a and b. It's only few extra lines. If you really have a lot of keys, then you can set up a loop but only over known keys, so keep an array or similar. In either case, avoid just blindly looping over the input.

There are a few ways your approach could potentially be unsafe, and it's up to you to decide how likely these pitfalls will be.

One is that object types in TypeScript are not "exact" (to borrow a term from Flow, see microsoft/TypeScript#12936 for the feature request) meaning they can have more properties at runtime than TypeScript knows about.  That's a feature, not a bug; otherwise, you could never extend interfaces by adding properties, without breaking the contract of the extended interface. But it means that ops might have keys outside of those in Partial<Ops>:
const o = { a: "abc", b: 123, someOtherProp: true };
tester.setOps(o); // allowed

If one of those properties happens to share a key with some other members of Tester (so that a hasOwnProperty check doesn't eliminate it), you're in trouble.  Note that you've already sidestepped the error for this, by writing let key: keyof Ops before the loop. Looks like you did this on purpose, to avoid the error. (I don't see much "declare loop variable ahead of time" in the wild). This is unsafe but allowed for some reason; see microsoft/TypeScript#49882. See Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript? for more information.
If you want to handle this possibility at runtime you should only loop over the elements in a static array known to contain the keys of Ops, like ["a", "b"] as const.  Personally I'd say it's probably unlikely for something like this to happen.
The other problem is that you are allowed to narrow properties in subclasses of Tester. If such a subclass has an a or a b property narrower than string or number, like this:
class Jester extends Tester {
    a: "abc" = "abc";
    b: 123 = 123;
    constructor() { super({ a: "abc", b: 123 }) }
}

Now the subclass's setOps method runs the risk of assigning something incompatible to a and b. TypeScript sees this as being of the polymorphic this type, so when you assign this[key] = ⋯, TypeScript worries that this might be narrower than Tester. There's no great way to prevent such things at runtime, but again, I'd expect this to be unlikely.  The way to sidestep this error is to widen this to Tester, like
const thisTester: Tester = this;

and then do assignments on thisTester.

So that brings us to the main problem you're facing, which is a missing feature of TypeScript. You can't generally assign foo[key] = bar[key] if key isn't a single specific key known at compile time, even if foo and bar are of the same type.  TypeScript is only following the types of the expressions, not the identities of the variables in them.  So TypeScript can't tell the difference between the above assignment and foo[key1] = foo[key2], if key1 and key2 are of the same type.  If key happens to be a union, like keyof Ops, then that's a problem. If keyof Ops were a single key like "a", that would be fine because foo.a = bar.a is safe . But since it's "a" | "b", then key1 might be "a" while key2 might be "b" and that's unsafe. So TypeScript complains about that possibility, even when you only have one key.
There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#32693 to support that assignment, but for now, it's not part of the language.  The current workaround is to change the key so that it's generic, and importantly, the source and destination objects must be of identical types.  TypeScript needs to see foo[key] = bar[key] as being an assignment from Foo[K] to itself, where K is generic.  Anything else will cause TypeScript to lose the thread.
We can refactor to generics by switching from the for k in loop to an Object.keys().forEach() callback, where instead of writing let k: keyof Ops to avoid an error, we write Object.keys(ops) as readonly (keyof Ops)[], for the same safety loosening.
The loop now looks like this:
setOps = (ops: Partial<Ops>) => {
    const thisOps: Ops = this; // widen this
    (Object.keys(ops) as readonly (keyof Ops)[]).forEach(
        <K extends keyof Ops>(key: K) => { // switch to generics
            if (ops[key] !== undefined) {
                thisOps[key] = ops[key]
            }
        })
}

So we've widened this from the polymorphic this to Ops. We have to do that widening, because even though Tester's instance type is a subtype of Ops, the assignent from Ops[K] to Tester[K] will fail. We need Ops[K] on both sides.
And the forEach() loop has a generic callback. Note that we have to check ops[key] for undefined to make sure we have Ops[K] and not Ops[K] | undefined.  Now the code compiles.

So that's how you can keep your general approach and have TypeScript not complain. I'm not sure it's much better than using type assertions (or, I guess, //@ts-ignore, but that's usually overkill). If you want something that does more or less the same thing that doesn't take any effort at all and TS doesn't even bother checking (because it's not implemented in TS), use Object.assign():
setOps = (ops: Partial<Ops>) => Object.assign(this, ops);

On the other hand if you want something both you and TS see as safe, you can avoid the loop entirely and just assign each property manually:
setOps = (ops: Partial<Ops>) => {        
    if (ops.a !== undefined) this.a = ops.a;        
    if (ops.b !== undefined) this.b = ops.b;
}

Obviously your use cases will drive whether you can choose either of these extremes, or whether you need to write a loop, and how you want to avoid/sidestep/suppress TypeScript compiler errors, and whether you care if those errors are warning you about something that could actually happen in theory (like ops having too many properties, or this being a subtype of Tester) or something actually impossible (like key being different members of the keyof Ops union on either side of the assignment).
Playground link to code
